# Minimum connectivity required for mean field to be a good approximation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, specific-reference

In spin models, it is known that mean field becomes a better approximation as the connectivity increases. My question is: Is there an estimate for the threshold connectivity (as a function of the system size, $N$), such that for connectivites greater than the threshold, mean field is a good approximation?

The values I am mainly interested in are the free energy and the magnetization, so the mean field approximation should be good in the sense that these values are accurate.

Comment: Well, a good approximation in what sense? If you want, say, close free energy and magnetization, or the ability to say that the system has a first order phase transition if its mean-field approximation has, then you might be able to extract estimates (although rather pessimistic, I suspect) from this paper: [arXiv:math/0207242](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207242). There are also two subsequent papers, if I remember correctly.

Comment: If you're interested in critical exponents, then you can, in principle, extract (probably bad) bounds from this paper: [arXiv:0712.0312](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0312).

Comment: @YvanVelenik I am mainly interested in good approximate values of the free energy and the magnetization. I edited the question to add this. If you are willing to add some details, you should post your first comment as an answer.

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): It seems the [tag:specific-reference] tag does not apply, cf. its [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info).

Comment: @Qmechanic Ok. You can edit it out if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Rigorous bounds comparing mean-field free energy and magnetization to their lattice counterparts, for various interaction ranges and dimensions, have been obtained in the following series of works (after many earlier works, see the references in these works):

[arXiv:math/0207242](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207242)

[arXiv:math-ph/0501067](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0501067)

[Commun. Math. Phys. 292 No 2 303–341 (2009)](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~lchayes/lchayes_website_folder/new_publications_folder/low_d_mft_cmp.pdf)

However, note that the bounds they get are probably quite poor (this was not the main point of their work). They treat in details a few models (Potts, XY, etc.), but the approach is not too specific. It is however essential that the model be reflection positive.

Although, this is not your main interest, let me mention, just to complete the answer, the following work, in which rigorous bounds are obtained (using the lace expansion) allowing to derive mean-field values for critical exponents of Ising, percolation and SAW models in either sufficiently high dimensions, or with sufficiently spread-out interactions:

[arXiv:0712.0312](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207242)

There are many other rigorous works on this topic, of course, but this should get you started.